# Add Dropdown selected item text to specific column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which is displaying the result set as follows

```
customer |2011 shipped qty|2011 sales price|2012 shipped qty|2012 sales price

    aa        1                     2.00              2                    5.50
    cc        2                     3.00              4                   6.25
```

and i am having two drop down lists as
monthdropdown1  and  quarterdropdown2

if user selects monthdropdown1 as jan,  in the grid result it should show as

```
customer|2011 shipped qty|2011 sales price| 2012 shipped qty| 2012 sales price|
          jan                 jan                 jan            jan

   aa     1                     2.00              2                    5.50
   cc     2                     3.00              4                   6.25
```

and also same as for quarter respectively

i just need to add the selected dropdowntext to the grid view header column

Note: Here my grid column property is autogeneratedcolumn = true

please find me the solution whether we can add selected text to gridview column header or can add saperate header column for the selected text

I have tried with this code in `Rowdatabound event` and was not worked for me

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    GridViewRow HeaderRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    TableCell HeaderCell2 = new TableCell();
    HeaderCell2.Text = (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    HeaderCell2.ColumnSpan = 0;
    HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell2);
    DataGrid1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderRow);
}
```

please find me any other solution if possible

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1" Style="visibility: visible" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E9EDF5"
                Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="12px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray"
                Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#298DC7" EnableViewState="false" CellSpacing="20"
                CellPadding="10" ShowFooter="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound">
                  <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Height="20px"/>
                    <alternatingrowstyle  Height="20px" BackColor="#E9EDF5"/>
<%--                OnRowCommand="DataGrid1__RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound">--%>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial;" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="White"
                    Font-Bold="True" Height="20" BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E9EDF5" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this link hope this will help you.

[On Button click change header text](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-change-gridview-header-text.html)

If you still facing the issue then please let me know i will create one sample for you.

In your code:

HTML:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1" Style="visibility: visible" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E9EDF5"
            Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="12px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray"
            Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#298DC7" EnableViewState="false" CellSpacing="20"
            CellPadding="10" ShowFooter="false" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Height="20px" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle Height="20px" BackColor="#E9EDF5" />
            <%--                OnRowCommand="DataGrid1__RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound">--%>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial;" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="White"
                Font-Bold="True" Height="20" BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E9EDF5" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Jan" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Feb" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Mar" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Quater1" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Quater2" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Quater3" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>

</form>
```

.CS:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<employee> obj = new List<employee>() { 
            new employee(1, "Sunny1"), 
            new employee(2, "Sunny2"), 
            new employee(3, "Sunny3"), 
            new employee(4, "Sunny4"), 
            new employee(5, "Sunny5"), 
            new employee(6, "Sunny6"), 
            new employee(7, "Anny7")};
    DataGrid1.DataSource = obj;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Changetext();
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Changetext();
}

private void Changetext()
{
    string str = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ";
    str += DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (DataGrid1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGrid1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text =   DataGrid1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + " " + str; //selectedvalue / text;

        }
    }
}
}
```

MODAL CLASS:

```
public class employee
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

public employee(int id, string _name)
{
    ID = id;
    Name = _name;
    Date = DateTime.Now;
}

public employee()
{

}

}
```

Use this code and let me know. With your html this is working fine.

Comment: thanks for the reply i will go through it and let u know.

Comment: i did't find any useful things in the link you provided

Comment: If you want to change column text at run time then you have to follow this. As per your question. On my end it is working fine.

Comment: i dont want to change the full text of my header column i just need to add(concatinate) the selected text and also keep in mind that my grid is having autogenerated columns

Comment: ok,Please show HTML of gridview in question. So that i can create same scenario on my end.

Comment: Did you checked update? Here column count will not create problem for you.

Comment: thanls for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dropdown looks something like this:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged" >
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="February" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You can manipulate the gridview header like this:-

```
protected void ddlMonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlMonth.SelectedValue != "-1")
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < DataGrid1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGrid1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text += "  " + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Similarily for Quarter dropdown. If you have to change the header text a lot consider using `StringBuilder`.

**Update:**

Use a `for` loop instead. I have started the loop from `1` because I want to skip the first column. Accordingly you can manipulate the loop.

Comment: is i was having the columns as autogeneraated the columns may increase more than 10 will this work with your code?

Comment: some time my columns may be reduce and sometimes my columns may increase